# Solving a linear equation system with 3 variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I have spend a lot time trying to see how I can concloude $a=b=c=0$ out of the data $$-3a+b+c=a-3b+c=a+b-3c=a+b+c=0.$$

Does somebody see an easy solution?

Comment: a solution is $$a=b=c=0$$

Comment: Yes, I know. But how does this system implies $a=b=c=0$?

Comment: Do you know how to solve a system of linear equations?

Comment: solve the first three equations at first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily conclude that $a=b=c=0$ by subtracting the various equations from each other notice that, $$(a+b-3c)-(a+b+c)=0-0 \Rightarrow -4c = 0 \Rightarrow c=0$$
also, $$(-3a+b+c)-(a+b+c)=0-0 \Rightarrow -4a=0 \Rightarrow a =0 $$
Finally subbing $a=0$ and $c=0$ into $a+b+c = 0$ we have $0+b+0=0 \Rightarrow b =0$

Answer (score 0):

solving the System
$$-3a+b+c=0$$
$$a-3b+c=0$$
$$a+b-3c=0$$
we get $$a=b=c=0$$ and this fulfills also our last equation
multiplying the second equation by $3$ and adding to the second we get
$$-8b+4c=0$$
doing the same with the third equation we have
$$4b-8c=0$$
multiplying the last by $2$ and adding we get $$-12c=0$$ thus $$c=0$$ and $b=0$ and $a=0$

Comment: Yes, but how have you solved this system? This is my main issue here :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$-3a+b+c=a-3b+c=a+b-3c=a+b+c=0$$

This is equivalent to four equations in three unknowns:

$$-3a+b+c=0$$
$$a-3b+c=0$$
$$a+b-3c=0$$
$$a+b+c=0$$

Without knowing whether there actually *is* a solution, we can look for one.

Subtract the fourth equation from the third:

$$-4c = 0$$

So this tells us $c=0$.

Subtract the fourth equation from the second:

$$-4b = 0$$

So this tells us $b=0$.

Similarly for the fourth and first equation: $a=0$.

Plugging in $a=b=c=0$ to each of the four equations gives a true statement ($0=0$), so that is indeed the solution.